# What is the number of connected components of solutions to $y^3 +3xy^2 - x^3 = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, contest-math

> What is the number of [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) of solutions to $y^3 +3xy^2 - x^3 = 1$

**Attempt**

$x^3 - 3y^2x + 1 - y^3 = 0$

$p := -3y^2$,   $q := 1 - y^3$

The discriminant is 
$Q = (p/3)^3 + (q/2)^2 = (-y^2)^3 + (1 - y^3)^2 / 8 = -y^6 + 1/8 -  2y^3 / 8 + y^6 / 8 = (-7y^6 - 2y^3 + 1/8) / 8$

Hence there exist $y$ such that $Q < 0$. They yield 3 real solutions and therefore 3 connected components.

But we need to prove the components do not intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three disjoint components to the solution curves.

Consider the disjoint regions formed by the following half lines:

$1)$                      $$ \{ (x,0): x\ge 0\}$$
$2)$                      $$ \{(x,-x): x\le 0\}$$
$3)$                           $$ \{(0,y): y\le 0 \}$$

Each component is contained in one and only one of the  rgions.

Thus the three branches of the solution curve are disjoint.